# SIMCOM A7600E trouble receiving UDP packages

Tags: udp, iot, at-command, modem, lte

I'm having trouble receiving UDP packages using a A7600E modem. I am required to send and receive UDP packages over LTE using dedicated IP addresses.

I am able to:

- obtain the dedicated IPv4 the ISP has allocated for us.
- send a package over the internet, The arriving package has the proper sending IP/port
- send and receive TCP packages using the TCP client and  server. (but my boss wants me to send UDPs)

There is no firewall at the ISP level, I've checked with another modem.

This is the command sequence I use to send packages. I cannot receive anything over UDP when I send packages to 79.118.XX.XX

```
ATI
Manufacturer: INCORPORATED
Model: A7600E-LNSE
Revision: A7600M7_V8.18.1
IMEI: 86999XXXXXXXXXX
+GCAP: +CGSM,+FCLASS,+DS

AT+CGMR
+CGMR: A818B03A7600M7

AT+CGATT=1
OK
AT+CGACT=1,1
OK

+CGEV: NW MODIFY 1,4
AT+CGPADDR=1
+CGPADDR: 1,46.97.XX.XX

OK
AT+NETOPEN
OK

+NETOPEN: 0
AT+CIPOPEN=0,"UDP",,,15000
+CIPOPEN: 0,0

AT+CIPSEND=0,10,"77.81.XX.XX",21000
>ewewwe4343
OK

+CIPSEND: 0,10,10
AT+CIPOPEN=1,"UDP",,,21000
+CIPOPEN: 1,0

OK
AT+CIPOPEN?
+CIPOPEN: 0,"UDP","79.118.XX.XX",21000,-1
+CIPOPEN: 1,"UDP","0.0.0.0",0,-1
+CIPOPEN: 2
+CIPOPEN: 3
+CIPOPEN: 4
+CIPOPEN: 5
+CIPOPEN: 6
+CIPOPEN: 7
+CIPOPEN: 8
+CIPOPEN: 9

OK
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: *"I'm having trouble receiving UDP packages"* -- The unit of data is not called a *"package"*, but rather a datagram or packet. *"I cannot receive anything over UDP ..."* -- That's only a summation of the problem (repeated 3 times in your post); you neglect to provide any description or details of which command(s) you issue and what does happen when you try to receive.

Comment: thank you for pointing me out that packages and packets are not interchangeable but I believe for someone who learned English without a teacher it can be excusable. Back to my issue: it's really hard to describe how the packets do not arrive, you know, once you netcat with TCP, alll works beautifully, switch to UDP, packets do not arrive, although you fallow the official documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I've emailed the SIMCom official support channel and they acknowledged there's a firmware issue with UDP on A7600 series and they provide me with an update which solved the issue. I'm not sure it will be a good think to post the link since it's a beta firmware and I hope they'll make it available soon on their official channels.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).